# I am trying to use PieChart in GWT. Error: No source code is available

Tags: java, gwt

While compiling my code I am getting this problem:

```
No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.PieChart; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 [ERROR] Line 30: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.PieChart.PieOptions; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 [ERROR] Line 38: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 [ERROR] Line 39: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 [ERROR] Line 40: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
```

I am using gwt 2.1 and visualizations. I tried adding an entry in *.gwt.xml, but it didnt help. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure that you have added

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.visualization.Visualization'/>
```

to your *.gwt.xml file? Because it seems to me that this is a reason of problem.

Comment: Hey thanks dimas. I was inheriting it in a wrong manner. I am feeling so dumb ! Thanks again

Comment: How to identify that what module do we have to inherit? 
i.e here we have identified : <inherits name='com.google.gwt.visualization.Visualization'/>

How to determine it?

Comment: This should be mentioned in documentation. For example for gwt visualization library this is mentioned in Getting Started section http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted